# Network map/mon tool clogs up telnet daemon / login processes

Tags: linux, multithreading, sockets, networking

We have an embedded Linux (Kernel 2.6.x / Busybox) system (IP camera/web server) which is being tripped over by a network mapping/monitoring tool (specifically [The Dude](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/The_Dude) but I think the problem is a general one) repeatedly probing the Telnet port.

The sequence of events is this:

- The tool probes port 23
- Our system's Telnet daemon (`busybox telnetd`) spawns a new `/bin/login` thread
- The tool, having satisfied itself there's something there, skips merrily on its way (it neither logs in nor closes the connection)
- This keeps happening (every N seconds) until there are so many sockets open that our system can no longer serve a web page through lack of sockets, and there are hundreds of `bin/login` processes hanging around.

Apologies for vagueness, full logs & wireshark captures are on a different PC at this moment.

As I see it, we need to do a couple of things:

- Put some sort of timeout on the telnet client / `bin/login` process if no login attempt is made
- Put some sort of limit on the number of ports the telnet client can have open at any time
- Kill off hanging / zombie sockets (TCP timeout / keepalive config?)

I'm not 100% clear on the correct approach to these three, given that the device is also serving web pages and streaming video so changes to system globals may impact the other services. I was a little surprised that Busybox seems to be open to what's effectively the world's slowest DDOS attack.

**Edit:**
I've worked out what I think is a reasonable way round this, [a new question started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30574630/alias-cmd-to-do-x-then-cmd-transparently) for ironing out the wrinkles in that idea. Basically, `login` exits as soon as someone logs in, so we can kill logins with (relative) impunity when a new instance is launched.

Comment: How about disabling telnet access altogether (and maybe use SSH instead for acccessing the box if/when needed)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, let me answer my own question by [linking to myself answering my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30574630/alias-cmd-to-do-x-then-cmd-transparently/30594032#30594032) on killing zombie logins each time a new one is spawned.

The solution is forcing telnetd to run a script instead of `/bin/login`, where the script kills any other instances of `/bin/login` before running a new one. Not ideal but hopefully solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> The tool, having satisfied itself there's something there, skips merrily on its way (it neither logs in nor closes the connection)

That is an issue and in fact a type of DOS attack.

> This keeps happening (every N seconds) until there are so many sockets open that our system can no longer serve a web page through lack of sockets, and there are hundreds of bin/login processes hanging around.

Apart from stopping the DOS attack you might want to mitigate it using some tools. In this specific case you might want to configure low TCP timeouts and thus get the sockets closed soon after they are open due to inactivity on the other end and thus the *login* processes should be terminated as well.

Comment: Pavel - I did say in my question it's effectively a DOS attack, although it seems to be more down to all of the orphaned `login` processes than hanging sockets if my investigations are accurate.

Comment: As far as I know the login process waits for input from the socket and so if the socket gets closed due to inactivity on the other end, the login process should be terminated.