# Alias <cmd> to "do X then <cmd>" transparently

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, alias, io-redirection

The title sucks but I'm not sure of the correct term for what I'm trying to do, if I knew that I'd probably have found the answer by now!

**The problem:**

Due to an over-zealous port scanner (customer's network monitor) and an overly simplistic telnet daemon (busybox linux) every time port 23 gets scanned, telnetd launches *another* instance of `/bin/login` waiting for user input via telnet.

As the port scanner doesn't actually try to login, there is no session, so there can be no session timeout, so we quickly end up with a squillion zombie copies of `/bin/login` running.

**What I'm trying to do about it:**

`telnetd` gives us the option (`-l`) of launching *some other thing* rather than `/bin/login` so I thought we could replace `/bin/login` with a bash script that kills old login processes then runs `/bin/login` as normal:

```
#!/bin/sh
# First kill off any existing dangling logins
# /bin/login disappears on successful login so
# there should only ever be one
killall -q login

# now run login
/bin/login
```

But this seems to return immediately (no error, but no login prompt). I also tried just chaining the commands in telnetd's arguments:

`telnetd -- -l "killall -q login;/bin/login"`

But this doesn't seem to work either (again - no error, but no login prompt). I'm sure there's some obvious wrinkle I'm missing here.

*System is embedded Linux 2.6.x running Busybox so keeping it simple is the greatly preferred option.*

**EDIT**: OK I'm a prat for not making the script executable, with that done I get the `login:` prompt but after entering the username I get nothing further.

Comment: Did you set the execute bit for your script?

Comment: Someone still uses `telnet` for what is was originally created? To login? Wow.

Comment: Does the `-l` flag take a shell script literal like that second example? I would expect it to require something that can be executed (like a binary or possibly a shell script with the execute bit and an appropriate shebang line).

Comment: See edits - I've made the script executable, correct group & permissions. Now get `login:` but no further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, I fixed it, as I suspected there was a wrinkle I was missing:

**exec** /bin/login

I needed `exec` to hand control over to `/bin/login` rather than just call it.

So the telnet daemon is started thusly:

```
/usr/sbin/telnetd -l /usr/sbin/not_really_login
```

The contents of the not-really-login script are:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo -n "Killing old logins..."
killall -q login
echo "...done"
exec /bin/login
```

And all works as it should, on telnet connect we get this:

```
**MOTD Etc...**

Killing old logins......done

login: zero_cool
password:
```

And we can login as usual.

The only thing I haven't figured out is if we can detect the exit-status of `/bin/login` (if we killed it) and print a message saying `Too slow, sucker!` or similar. TBH though, that's a nicety that can wait for a rainy day, I'm just happy our stuff can't be DDOS'ed over Telnet anymore!

Answer (score 0):

Check that your script has the execute bit set. Permissions should be the same as for the original binary including ownership.

As for `-l`: My guess is that it tries to execute the command `killall -q login;/bin/login` (that's one word).

Since this is an embedded system, it might not write logs. But you should check `/var/log` anyway for error messages. If there are none, you should be able to configure it using the documentation: http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/log.overview

Comment: Script now made executable - see edit. Logging via syslog is enabled but no messages from login appear.

Comment: Put a bunch of `echo 1 >> /tmp/debug` in the script to see whether it's called at all and how far it gets.